# excel VBA find doesn't work with specific values

Tags: excel, vba, find

Find function works quite good, but there are few exceptions that I don't understand. I have userform, I use find method to get all information about product/item by its code and showing it after button is pressed in userform. Product codes in my table consists of such codes: 1230, 1231, 1232... 1239. The main problem is that I don't understand why numbers like: 1-9, 123 doesn't trigger the msgbox "Can't find product"?

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim totalRows As Long
Dim itemCode As Range
Set itemCode = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A:A").Find(Me.txtCode.Value)

totalRows = Worksheets("Data").Range("A:A").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

'searching by code
If Trim(Me.txtCode.Value) = "" Then
    Me.txtCode.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Need item code"
    Exit Sub
End If

If itemCode Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Can't find product with such code"
End If

    For i = 2 To totalRows
        If Trim(Cells(i, 1)) = Trim(Me.txtCode) Then
            txtName.Text = Cells(i, 2)
            'unit of measurement name
            txtUnitName.Text = Cells(i, 3)
            txtPrice.Text = Cells(i, 4)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use `xlWhole` in your find function. now for 1-9 the function can find those in any value like 1234, 2014 etc.

Comment: Also, you can get rid of your bulky `For Loop` in this case. As you already have the row number in which code is present by using `itemcode.Row`, no need to loop and find `i` in which value is present.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Mikku, your suggestion work'ed as a charm and yeah, will erase the for loop, thank you :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want an exact match, you should add `LookAt:=xlWhole` to the find parameters.

Otherwise this should do about the same thing, without using find:

```vb
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim totalRows As Long
Dim arrData As Variant

With Worksheets("Data")
    totalRows = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arrData = .Range("A1:D" & totalRows)
End With

'searching by code
If Trim(Me.txtCode.Value) = "" Then
    Me.txtCode.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Need item code"
    Exit Sub
End If

For i = 2 To totalRows
    If Trim(arrData(i, 1)) = Trim(Me.txtCode) Then
        txtName.Text = arrData(i, 2)
        'unit of measurement name
        txtUnitName.Text = arrData(i, 3)
        txtPrice.Text = arrData(i, 4)
        Exit For
    End If

    If i = totalRows Then MsgBox "Can't find product with such code"
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: where is find function in this ?

Comment: @Mikku there isn't, I've decided against using Find for my answer.

Comment: But Find function is way faster than loops. Anyways,  loops also get the job done.

Comment: @Mikku, agree to disagree. For a one off like in this case, yes.. using find to determine if a value exists is probably desirable. However to loop through each cell afterwards, if you have lots and lots of data, is just to slow, hence using an array instead. And if you have only little data, it doesn't make any difference for the eye either way.

Comment: Yeah But even for the Array you will have to loop through it's elements eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

`Set itemCode = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A:A").Find(Me.txtCode.Value)`

With:

`Set itemCode = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A:A").Find(Trim(Me.txtCode.Value), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)`